# Why isn't comparing of two bars working correctly?

Tags: pine-script

I know I ask too much questions on this issue but I'm pretty desperate right now.

I have the code. The first part of it finds a local maximum. The second part SHOULD find the closest bar from the right which is bigger then the local maximum.

E.g. we have: 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 in this order. 3 is the local maximum. And we have 4 which should be marked because it is the next number bigger then the local maximum.

```
//@version=3
study("Max", overlay = true)

//===== THE FIRST PART BELOW =====
// Finds the local max.

locMax = na
in = 1

for i = in to 10
    if close[in] > close[in - 1] and close[in] > close[in + 1]
        locMax := close[in]
        break

//===== THE SECOND PART BELOW =====
// SHOULD find the next bar bigger then the local max.
// But it marks every bar bigger then the previous one.

b = na
ind = in - 1

for i = ind to 0
    if close[ind] > close[in]
        b := close[ind]
        break

plotarrow(locMax, offset = -in)
plotchar(b, offset = -ind, char = 'X', color = black)
```

Why does it mark every bar bigger then the previous one? I don't understand. How to make it mark only one needed bar?

Note that I asked a similar question but it was about the first part of my code. And I also deleted it.

Comment: `b := close[ind]` Are you sure that's correct? Maybe there must be `b := close[i]` ?

Comment: I don't remember already. I gave up on this problem like 5 days ago.